# Битовый размер целочисленного типа

Tags: c++

Есть стандартный, шаблонный способ получить размер типов:

```
template <typename Type>
size_t GetSize()
{
   static_assert( false, "Unknown");
   return 0;
}
template <>
size_t GetSize< int32_t >()
{
    return 32;
}
template <>
size_t GetSize< char >()
{
    return CHAR_BIT;
}
```

Или нужно вручную написать для всех типов?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Достаточно `sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT`, потому что `sizeof(char)` всегда равен 1.

Comment: Если не прав - поправьте: не всегда `CHAR_BIT` равен 8 (может быть и больше), на некоторых архитектурах размер `char` может быть равен и 2, и 4.

Comment: Какому именно стандарту ?

Comment: Собственно, [вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char/2098444#2098444)